# Why is this linq query with anonymous type faster than anything else I try?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq

I have this query, it selects A LOT of user records from a table. This code block takes 16 seconds from my local/debug machine (more like 5 in production). Anything I do to make this more efficient doubles the amount of time the method takes to return the results. Examples of other things I've tried are below. I don't understand how selecting an anonymous type and having the extra middle section iterating through the anonymous type can possibly be faster than without.

This block takes 16 seconds:

```
List<BoAssetSecurityUser> userList = new List<BoAssetSecurityUser>();
using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{

    var query = from ui in context.User_Information
                where (ui.AssetCustomerID == 1 && 
                          (ui.GlobalID != "1TPTEMPUSER" || 
                           ui.GlobalID == null))
                select new { ui };
    var result =
    from q in query
    select new
    {
        UserId = q.ui.UserID,
        FirstName = q.ui.FirstName,
        LastName = q.ui.LastName,
        UserName = q.ui.Username,
        Globalid = q.ui.GlobalID

    };
    foreach (var user in result)
    {
        BoAssetSecurityUser boAssetSecUser = new BoAssetSecurityUser();
        boAssetSecUser.UserId = user.UserId;
        boAssetSecUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        boAssetSecUser.LastName = user.LastName;
        boAssetSecUser.UserName = user.UserName;
        boAssetSecUser.GlobalId = user.Globalid;
        userList.Add(boAssetSecUser);
    }
}
return userList;
```

This takes over 45 seconds to complete:

```
List<BoAssetSecurityUser> userList = new List<BoAssetSecurityUser>();
using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{

    var query = (from ui in context.User_Information
                where (ui.AssetCustomerID == 1 && 
                          (ui.GlobalID != "1TPTEMPUSER" || 
                           ui.GlobalID == null))
                select ui).ToList();
    foreach (var user in query)
    {
        BoAssetSecurityUser boAssetSecUser = new BoAssetSecurityUser();
        boAssetSecUser.UserId = user.UserID;
        boAssetSecUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        boAssetSecUser.LastName = user.LastName;
        boAssetSecUser.UserName = user.Username;
        boAssetSecUser.GlobalId = user.GlobalID;
        userList.Add(boAssetSecUser);
    }
}
return userList;
```

This example also takes over 45 seconds to complete:

```
List<BoAssetSecurityUser> userList = new List<BoAssetSecurityUser>();
using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{

    var query = from ui in context.User_Information
        where (ui.AssetCustomerID == 1 && 
                  (ui.GlobalID != "1TPTEMPUSER" || 
                   ui.GlobalID == null))
                select new { ui };

    foreach (var user in query)
    {
        BoAssetSecurityUser boAssetSecUser = new BoAssetSecurityUser();
        boAssetSecUser.UserId = user.ui.UserID;
        boAssetSecUser.FirstName = user.ui.FirstName;
        boAssetSecUser.LastName = user.ui.LastName;
        boAssetSecUser.UserName = user.ui.Username;
        boAssetSecUser.GlobalId = user.ui.GlobalID;

        userList.Add(boAssetSecUser);
    }
}
return userList;
```

Comment: how many fields you have in `User_Information`, it appears you are only selecting limited fields anonymous type

Comment: is user_information of type BoAssetSecurityUser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely because `ui`'s type has more properties than the 5 you're interested in. The `new { ui }` anonymous type is unnecessary; your first example is faster because you tell it before you iterate the list (and thus go to the DB) that you're only interested in those 5 fields. In the other examples, you iterate the list, thus pulling the whole `ui` objects, even though you only use 5 of its properties.

This code should only pull the 5 properties, and so be as fast as your first example, while being more concise:

```
List<BoAssetSecurityUser> userList = new List<BoAssetSecurityUser>();
using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{
    var query = from ui in context.User_Information
                where (ui.AssetCustomerID == 1 && (ui.GlobalID != "1TPTEMPUSER" || ui.GlobalID == null))
                select new
                {
                    ui.UserID,
                    ui.FirstName,
                    ui.LastName,
                    ui.Username,
                    ui.GlobalID
                };

    foreach (var user in query)
    {
        BoAssetSecurityUser boAssetSecUser = new BoAssetSecurityUser();
        boAssetSecUser.UserId = user.UserID;
        boAssetSecUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        boAssetSecUser.LastName = user.LastName;
        boAssetSecUser.UserName = user.Username;
        boAssetSecUser.GlobalId = user.GlobalID;
        userList.Add(boAssetSecUser);
    }
}
return userList;
```

Comment: I understand, that middle section iterating through the anonymous type is actually executing the query and only selecting the desired fields. Yes, it has a handful of columns - your adjustment shaved off 2 seconds, this was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's more about the amount of data your bringing from the database. The first query selects only a few columns while the others bring all of them.

Do you have large columns on this table?

Answer (score 1):

It is faster because you only fetch 5 properties per line with your anonymous type. I don't now how many fields you have in `User_Information`, but they're all fetched when you use `.ToList()` on your query, you probably get much more data than needed.